# Debugging physical device ends at :"frame not available"

Tags: android, android-studio

Trying to debug **any app** (doesn't matter) by usb on my device(Samsung s6) with breakpoints,
debugging starts normally, but when I keep pressing the "step over" button (exactly when "On create" ends)the app goes to the background and the debugger shows "frame is not available" and the console shows:"Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'".

When I try to debug by the emulator things look normal.

So far I have tried:

Disabling and re enabling developer options/usb debugging ext..

Stop Adb and restart.

Install specific usb driver for my device.

Changing port on ADM.

Restart mobile device and Android

Uninstall and Reinstall Android Studio.

When I try to **run** the App on the device, it performs normall and doesn't crash or move to the background.

any suggestions will be greatley apriciated..

["frame is not available"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuX7I.png)

["Disconnected from the target"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rw8uk.png)